# Added a method to a class, not seen by debugger, AOS server crashes

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I added a new method to the `CustVendPaym` class called `sendersBankCompanyStatementName` of type `BankCompanyStatementName`.

This is the code of said method:

```
public BankCompanyStatementName sendersBankCompanyStatementName(BankCompanyStatementName _sendersBankCompanyStatementName = sendersBankCompanyStatementName)
{
    sendersBankCompanyStatementName = _sendersBankCompanyStatementName;
    return sendersBankCompanyStatementName;
}
```

I added the definition in the `classDeclaration` method:

```
BankCompanyStatementName        sendersBankCompanyStatementName;
```

Then in the method `vendPaym` in the `VendOutPaym` class, a new instance of `VendPaym` (which extends `CustVendPaym`) is created:

```
vendPaym = new VendPaym();
//A bunch of properties are set then one I created:
vendPaym.sendersBankCompanyStatementName     (bankAccountTable.BankCompanyStatementName);
```

If I break there, I see the assignment with the value I'm expecting working correctly, but then the debugger (watch) never actually shows the new property I added with the value that's supposed to be in it.

Then if I just continue code execution, the AOS server in which I'm developing just crashes :|

Any ideas, am I doing something obviously wrong ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** If I rollback my changes (that is deleting the newly added method and removing any references to it) everything works as it was before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you compiled forward the CustVendPaym class?

Comment: I have a project with all these classes, and I've compiled the whole project. I've also done a data dictionary sync., no go :(

Comment: No, I mean right click on the CustVendPaym class -> Add-Ins -> Compile forward

Comment: It's because CustVendPaym is a very low level abstract class that's extended by many other classes.  I'd guess that he only compiled `CustVendPaym` and `VendOutPaym`, but there are other classes that are constructed from `VendOutPaym` that probably needed compiled to function properly, that are extended in one way or another from `CustVendPaym`

Comment: What Alex K said - when you change a class that is extended (or has "children", depending on your lingo ;) you must compile forward so that all the extended classes are compiled and the change is available to them. I never had the AOS crash on me because of that, but that's our beloved AX, right :)